# how to deal with TypeError: polarity_scores() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, typeerror, vader

When i am running

```
df=[]
DataTab['scores'] = DataTab['headline_text'].apply(lambda x: vader.polarity_scores(x))
DataTab.head()
```

I M GETTING THIS ERROR

```
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-157ec346f35d> in <module>
      1 df=[]
----> 2 DataTab['scores'] = DataTab['headline_text'].apply(lambda x: vader.polarity_scores(x))
      3 DataTab.head()
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4040             else:
   4041                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4042                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4043 
   4044         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
<ipython-input-248-157ec346f35d> in <lambda>(x)
      1 df=[]
----> 2 DataTab['scores'] = DataTab['headline_text'].apply(lambda x: vader.polarity_scores(x))
      3 DataTab.head()
TypeError: polarity_scores() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'*
```

PLEASE HELP ME
WHAT SHOULD I INSTALL OR CHANGE

Comment: You have to show your data sample so that we could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Fixed it by initialising variable and then using it in lambda.